# Locution adverbiale : « si besoin est »

Tags: expressions, locutions

> En maîtrisant l'anglais je pourrais enseigner en cette langue, si
>   besoin est.

Lors d'une présentation auprès d'un public académique, peut-on utiliser de nos jours la locution *si besoin est* ? Quel est la différence avec *si nécessaire* et tout simplement *si besoin* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un grand OUI : une variante plus courante est *si nécessaire*, mais le registre de langage de *si besoin est* correspond parfaitement à une présentation académique.

Comment: Also just *si besoin*, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: @Luke: Non *si besoin* sans *est* n'est pas idiomatique, mais on peut dire « si y'a besoin » dans un registre familier. Il y a aussi « au besoin ».

Comment: @Stéphane Merci !

Comment: @LukeSawczak Voir [Colignon](https://jeanpierrecolignon.wordpress.com/tag/besoinsi-besoin-au-besoin/) et [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=si+besoin.&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csi%20besoin%20.%3B%2Cc0) ;  qq ex. : Referler les spis, ranger les voiles d'avant si besoin, faire de l'ordre, si besoin ranger les poids si les conditions ont changé et, s’ il y a de l'eau …

entravez, mettez vous à max distance pour avoir le temps de réentraver si besoin.

Answer (score 1):

Noter que comme 'est' est un verbe on le conjugue. On pourrait le mettre au passé, si besoin était.