# Si besoin est, si besoin, si nécessaire : Y a-t-il des différences ?

Tags: usage, locutions

Récemment j'ai posé la question [Locution adverbiale : « si besoin est »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30479/locution-adverbiale-si-besoin-est) concernant la locution adverbiale *si besoin est*. Je me demande s'il y a des différences entre cette locution et « si nécessaire » (hormis le registre de langue) ou bien avec « si besoin » (sans « est » à la fin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ma connaissance il n'y a aucune différence de sens entre **si besoin** et **si nécessaire** les deux sont synonymes et parfaitement interchangeables ou du moins je n'arrive pas à trouver une phrase pour laquelle ce n'est pas le cas.

Comment: Merci. Est-ce également le cas pour si besoin est ?

Comment: Je ne pourrais pas te citer la règle exacte mais par exemple la phrase "Je peux le faire si besoin" me semble plus correcte que "Je peux le faire si besoin est". On dirait qu'il y a une redondance dans la seconde, on sent que le "est" est en trop mais les deux phrases seraient parfaitement comprises par un natif.

Comment: Le *est* n'est pas en trop, au contraire. Il y a ellipse du verbe dans la tournure familière *si besoin*, comme il y a ellipse de *c'est* dans *si nécessaire*.

Comment: Je ne crois pas avoir entendu *si besoin* au Québec, mais *au besoin* y est communément utilisé, et ne me semble pas être une tournure familière ou populaire à éviter particulièrement.

Answer (score 1):

Non, il n'y a aucune différence. On peut dire de façon plus longue, mais qui n'est toujours pas trop longue, « **si c'est nécessaire.** » et « **s'il y a besoin.** » ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%27il+y+a+besoin.&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cs%27il%20y%20a%20besoin%20.%3B%2Cc0)).

On s'aperçoit en vérifiant un ngram ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=si+besoin.%2Csi+besoin+est.&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csi%20besoin%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csi%20besoin%20est%20.%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csi%20besoin%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csi%20besoin%20est%20.%3B%2Cc0)) que l'expression « si besoin est », jusqu'à très récemment a toujours été beaucoup plus utilisée, et qu'il n'y a que à peu près depuis 2004, dans la grimpée en flèche de la fréquence « si besoin »  qui a commencé vers 1995, que l'on utilise un peu plus cette dernière expression. Donc, « si besoin est » devrait toujours donner l'impression de faire partie de l'usage naturel. C'est l'impression que cette expression me fait.